# bitwise operation, printing of bits depends of which putchar is put first...?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, putchar

I'm simply trying to print an unsigned int as bits, but it appears my code:

```
void checksWithOne(unsigned int userInput)
{
   int i = 0, a = 0;

   for (i = sizeof(int)*8-1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      a = (userInput&(1<<i));
      if (a==1)
      {
         putchar('1');
      }
      else
      {
         putchar('0');
      }
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Only works if the if statement is changed as such (replacing 1s and 0s):

```
      if (a==0)
      {
         putchar('0');
      }
      else
      {
         putchar('1');
      }
```

It's beyond me as to why that is... any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: to understand problem print values of `a` in first code's for loop you will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second code works because you prints `'0'` when `a` is == `0` else `'1'`. Accordingly in first code piece, `if(a==1)` should be `if(a)` that means print `1` if `a` is not `0` (Rremember every non-zero value is true   in C).

The thing is `a = (userInput & (1<<i));` is not always `1` but `a` can be a number that is either zero or a number in which only one bit is one (e.g. ...00010000)

Answer (score 1):

The result of `a = (userInput&(1<<i))` will be either `1<<i` or `0`, (not `1` or `0`). So change:

```
  if (a==1)
```

to:

```
  if (a != 0)
```

and your code should work.